# URLs with javascript:false in them being requested by clients of my website. Why?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

Our .Net 4.5 production website is recieving multiple requests like this:

- http://fakeurl.com/folder/javascript:false
- http://fakeurl.com/javascript:false

The requests are getting intercepted by the .Net request validation as they should but I would like to understand where those requests are coming from. The users are valid users and for some reason their browser seems to be appending 'javascript:false' to the request We have only seen it from a handful of users with the following User-Agent strings

- Mozilla/4.0+compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.0;+Trident/4.0;+FunWebProducts;+SLCC1;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+Media+Center+PC+5.0;+InfoPath.1;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30618;+FunWebProducts;
- Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Win64;+x64;+Trident/5.0

Does anyone have an idea of where the javascript:false is coming from? If we cannot prevent the users browser from sending this extra string is there a way to just strip invalid characters from the request instead of throwing an Exception?

Comment: Check the referrer for bad links.

Comment: Have those users run malware detection

Comment: It only happens to a few users and I haven't heard from them directly. I only noticed because the site alerts us when there are errors and I was getting annoyed by this particular alert.

Answer (score 2):

These requests are from user agents mindlessly following a `<a href="javascript:false">` or similar. They are bots faking a browser user agent. The bots are interpreting the javascript URL as a relative URL because they are buggy or their human owners don't care.

This is a normal occurrence when you run a website. You'll see all kind of crazy stuff in the logs.